# preserve variable in jquery callback handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Jquery**

```
operations = {
    index: 0,
    update: function(target) {
        proxiedThis = this;
        return function(event) {        
            target.append(proxiedThis.index);
        }
    }
}
options = $.extend(operations);
options.index = 1;
$.each($('.clickable'), function(i, element) {
    $(element).on('click', $.proxy(operations.update, options, $('#target')).call());        
    options.index += 1;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <!-- include jQuery -->
    <body>
        <p class="clickable">click-me-1</p>
        <p class="clickable">click-me-2</p>
        <p class="clickable">click-me-3</p>
        <p id="target">Target</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**What I want to achieve**
While registering a callback handler for each element in `$.each` block, I want to pass different `options.index` variables. `1` for the first, `2` for the second, and `3` for the third.

**What happens now is:**
It passes 3 (the last value in the loop) to all of the callback handlers.

**Would also like to know:** why this happens

**Code also available in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mfissehaye/aso6q3tx/)**

Comment: `options` is a reference to the same object for each callback, so the value change.

Comment: @Hacketo then can I clone options as $.extend({}, options) and pass it to have a separate clone for each callback

Comment: Fiddle isn't working..

Comment: @Repo okay thanks. It's now working

Comment: I still get - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : (index):28

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/aso6q3tx/3/ here is fixed fiddle.

Comment: @Repo Oh so sorry. Please try now or copy and paste just the jquery code from the content of this question.

Comment: @Hacketo `$.extend({}, options)` doesn't help either. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `options` is the same object for each callback. What you could do is

```
$.each($('.clickable'), function(i, element) {
    var options = $.extend({}, operations);
    options.index = i + 1;
    $(element).on('click', $.proxy(operations.update, options)($('#target')) );
});
```

Also you have to make sure that `proxiedThis` is not global `var proxiedThis = this;`

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/urdscthf/)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot. But please explain why making proxiedThis global would be a porblem.

Comment: Because then the value of `proxiedThis` will change when you do `proxiedThis = this`. To make this variable local to the scope you need the `var` keyword.